# Pass JavaScript variable to C# method in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to do the following in MVC: I have been trying to call a C# Method `ReplaceSpecialCharactersInURL` from JavaScript as follows

```
var SuppName= obj.data('suppliername');
var NewSupp= '@Common.ReplaceSpecialCharactersInURL(SuppName)';
```

But it throws me an error as follows :

> The name 'SuppName' does not exist in the current context

On the other hand it runs ok when I pass the name directly as this

```
var NewSupp= '@Common.ReplaceSpecialCharactersInURL("NewName")';
```

What I can make out is I cant pass JavaScript variable to c# Method

Let me know if such a thing is possible, and if so, then how.

Comment: @Common.ReplaceSpecialCharactersInURL(Supp)

Answer (score 1):

It's impossible, because Razor view engine knows nothing about your Javascript.

Comment: Ok, but it is working if i a pass a string, and dont work if i pass a string variable...

Comment: You are passing a valid C# string literal, that's why everything is OK. But you can't pass Javascript variable.

Comment: I don't think it is. C# code is executing while preparing Response and Javascript code is executing when this response reachs the client side. So I think it's unlikely if they can interact in such way.

You can pass some data for Javascript via C# (as you've done with string literal) because it executes at server side earlier then Javascript comes into action.

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible in the way you're trying to do it because Razor is processed on the server side and JavaScript is processed on the client side.

One option you have is to ask the server to call `Common.ReplaceSpecialCharactersInURL` using an Ajax Request, like this:

Server:

```
public ActionResult ReplaceCharacters(string url) {
    string result = Common.ReplaceSpecialCharactersInURL(url);
    return Json(new { result });
}
```

Client:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var SuppName= obj.data('suppliername');

    // Using jQuery Ajax here.
    $.post('@Url.Action("ReplaceCharacters")', { url: SuppName },
        function (data) {
            var newUrl = data.result;
            // newUrl here is the result of Common.ReplaceSpecialCharactersInURL
        }
    );
</script>
```

Another option would be to create a JavaScript version of your server-side function (`ReplaceSpecialCharactersInURL`), but in some cases that could be really hard or even impossible.

---

**Extra:**

I don't know what your `ReplaceSpecialCharactersInURL` does, but you should check the [`encodeURIComponent`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_encodeuri.asp) JavaScript function just in case it helps you with this particular issue.